# How to update the label in MainWindow from controller class?

Tags: c#, user-interface, mono, label, gtk2

My controller is a main method which implement my model and do the calculations. My MainWindow class has one button and it will update the result from my controller once it clicked. Now I have problem regrading how to update labels from my controller.

Button method is my view

```
public void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

 }
```

I try to access MainWindow class from my controller class

```
            Application.Init();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
            //here I want to use win object to access my view
            //but I can not access my labels

            win.Show();
            Application.Run();
```

The strange part is:

```
win.Button1_Clicked.first_label
```

I only can access label through my button which is totally not make any sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the labels or any other control in the form, you should write a corresponding method with a public modifier.

Making labels/controls public is a bad practice.

Therefore, my suggested solution would be to write a public method with, e.g. a string argument to set the text;

e.g.:

```
public void SetLabelText(string text)
{
    LabelResult.Text = text;
}
```

EDIT:

to set the text use

```
win.SetLabelText("some text");
```